# low voltage battery disconnect from regulator

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

I am regulating a lithium ion battery to 3.3V and I want the regulator output to shut off when the regulator can no longer supply 3.3V. I am having trouble finding an IC that would do this, and this charger with a low battery disconnect is all I could find: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4071fc.pdf

It says there is low battery disconnect from VCC at 3.2V.
It says under "Applications" that it is for energy harvesting, so I don't understand if it's really suitable for what I want to do. I need a charger in my circuit too, so that would be useful. I want to make sure I'm looking at this correctly...is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do a search on LDO regulator. TI Maxim and Linear Tecnologies all have multiple low dropout regulators.

Comment: I want "undervoltage lockout" when the regulator output is below its specified 3.3V, and I don't see that.

Comment: I'm confused. If you have a lithium iron battery connected to the input of a regulator with a 3.3 volt output and the output of the regulator is connected to some load, wouldn't it make more sense to disconnect the battery from the regulator when the regulator's output voltage fell below 3.3 volts, then connect it to the charger and charge it until it got topped off and then disconnect it from the charger and connect it back up to the regulator?

Comment: Lots of LDO parts have an enable input, that may be used to turn the regulator off. Set up a reference feed it to a comparator and latch the part off.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me whether the battery is disconnected from the regulator or the regulator output is off because I want the device I'm making to be portable, so the input voltage to the charger wouldn't be connected necessarily at the time it's needed. The device would be off and the user would know that it's time to charge up. The reference concept is confusing to me because the battery would be input to the reference, and if the battery voltage is dropping then the reference would be affected, right?

Comment: Does your lithium battery have a built-in battery protection circuit? If so, it will cut off the battery from over-discharge at some point (may not be the point you want, but it will happen). If your lithium battery does not have built-in protection, you are making a huge mistake. You need to add a protection circuit.

Comment: Are you talking about protection during the charging process? The MCP73831 charger I want to use has protection features (http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General%20IC/33244_SPCN.pdf). The lithium battery doesn't have built-in protection (does any coin cell?), but the regulator I want to use during operation (not charging) has overtemperature and short circuit current-limiting protection. Is that not good enough?

Comment: It is a coin cell? Can you provide a specification, please? I have never seen a lithium ion battery pack in a product which did not have a protection circuit built-in to it. As an example, you can take a look at Seiko battery protection IC's. They have hundreds of products of this type.

Comment: It's an LIR2450. Here's a datasheet: http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/LIR2450.pdf

Comment: It is a 120 mAh Lithium Ion cell. This is smaller than anything I have ever used in a product before, but this type of cell normally would use a redundant protection circuit to make sure it does not get over charged or over discharged. How do you plan to avoid discharging below 2.75V? The datasheet says that it should not be discharged below that point.

Comment: I plan to use the "power good" signal as an input to the shutdown pin that is part of the MCP1825 (The SHDN input is an active-low input signal that turns
the LDO on and off).

Comment: So let's walk through this. Battery discharges, PGOOD goes low, which asserts SHDN, so the regulator turns off. Cool. What causes the regulator to turn back on? PGOOD will not go high until SHDN goes high. So you will have to have a way to force SHDN high to turn the regulator back on or it will stay off forever. You may be able to come up with a good way to do that, but the point definitely needs to be addressed.

Comment: Also, the regulator quiescent current is 140 uA. So if you keep the regulator enabled all the time, the quiescent current alone will completely drain your battery in around 800 hours. If there is any other quiescent load in addition to the regulator quiescent current, then the situation will be even worse. Maybe that is OK. It would not be OK for the products that I work on, but it could be OK if you expect your device to be recharged frequently, and it doesn't have to survive in inventory for a year before the consumer opens it (and still boot up without charging first).

Comment: I didn't realize SHDN was linked to PGOOD like that, which seems weird to me because I think the best use of PGOOD would be to disable the output. Anyway, maybe it's actually best to use the PGOOD signal with a mosfet to control the battery connection to the MCP1825 input, because then there would be no current used by the MCP1825. If the SHDN method worked, the LDO output voltage would be off, but the regulator would still consume current...

Comment: On second thought, the mosfet idea probably isn't good either because it needs a power supply, which I wouldn't want to use from the drained battery...this is so hard, what's the best way to cut off the battery at low voltage??

Comment: I guess I could input the power good signal to the active low reset of my microcontroller, and my circuit wouldn't consume current, but the regulator would...

Comment: SHDN is not linked to PGOOD. I thought you were proposing to link them as a way to shut down the regulator when the output voltage drooped below the threshold. The MOSFET would not need a power supply. You would use P-channel MOSFET. Connect the source to the battery and drain to input of LDO. When the gate is low, the FET will be on. When the gate is equal to VBATT, the FET will be off.

Answer (score 3):

Why not you are going with a Switching regulator. Instead of LDO if you will go with the switching regulator, the backup for the device will be more since the efficiency of switching regulator is better than that of LDO's.

For example you can use [TPS62240DDCRG4](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62240.pdf). This regulator has the provision of under-voltage lockout. If the voltage at enable pin is less than 1.85 Volt the device will be shutdown. In your case the regulator should shut down at 3.2V, so you can use a voltage divider at regulator Enable pin in such a way that when your battery voltage is 3.2V, the enable pin should sense a voltage of around 1.8V.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXItdN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a lot of situations where a reference voltage is created inside a circuit to insure it behaves correctly under a wide variety of conditions of input voltage and temperature. As an example, you want your multimeter to measure voltage correctly from the time you put in a new battery, until you have to replace the battery. Or a temperature sensor should give the same output at the same temperature regardless of the battery pack.
There are simple circuits to do this. Google zener voltage reference.
And there are more sophisticated versions for more demanding jobs. see bandgap reference.
These are heavily enough used that these circuits are made into 3 terminal parts.
A commonly used one is the tl431v.
A quick search turned up the circuit shown in eevblog for low battery cutout.
Adjust r2 and r3 to get the setpoint to kill vout.
http://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/li-ion-battery-low-voltage-cut-off-circuit-needed-for-project/
Note, I used an SCR since there is no 3 terminal voltage reference.

Comment: Thanks for the information. After searching for a while I found a low cost Microchip IC (MCP1825) that is a 3.3V regulator with a "power good output" that "is an open-drain output used to indicate when the LDO output voltage is within 92%
(typically) of its nominal regulation value". This is the datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22056b.pdf That could be a substitute for using a comparator shut off, right? I want to use as few parts as possible, so that seems more convenient.

Comment: This is not really a micro-power circuit since it loads the battery with 47k + 18k all the time, even after it cuts off the power from the rest of the board. Depending on what the OP's intention is, it might work for him or her, but it does not protect the battery from over-discharge, and it will result in terrible standby life for the device (unless the battery is huge).

Comment: To @cheeto, the powergood signal could possibly be useful to turn off a FET and prevent over-discharge of the battery. But what will cause the FET to turn back on? You need to think it through to make sure that the regulator will be re-enabled or the FET will be turned back on after the battery is charged back up.

Comment: There is a shutdown pin on the MCP1825 that disables the LDO, so I can input the power good signal to that pin to disable the LDO until the battery voltage is high enough again.